# What is negative energy?

Tags: energy, casimir-effect

From what I've read negative energy is based on the Dirac sea concept of virtual particles. Negative energy is referenced by [Casimir effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) of virtual particle concentration differences between the space outside the experiment and inside the experiment i.e. the two uncharged metal plates. So is negative energy simply negative virtual particle flux?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the Casimir Effect the vacuum state between the plates is at a lower energy state than that outside them. Taking the normal vacuum as baseline, the area between the plates is negative energy.

Comment: Correct. The explanation given for the lower energy state is the difference in concentration of virtual particles otherwise Casimir forces should be zero, regardless of baseline.

Comment: The point being that it is negative because we assign a value of zero to the vacuum outside the plates.